# Shared PK in entity mismatch

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa-2.0

I'm developing an example web-application, using JPA 2.0 entities, Hibernate 3.6.2 and Spring 3. The example contains two tables in a one-to-one relationship, the parent entity is Client and the child is Address, the PK in Address references the Client table (identifying relationship).

Running the JUnit tests, I've noted a peculiar problem with these two entities, the problem it's that the child entity persists with the (parentId + 1), my mappings are as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable{
    private Long clientId;
    private Address address;
    //Other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getClientId(){return this.clientId;}
    public void setClientId(Long id){this.clientId=id;}

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="clientid",referencedColumnName="fk_clientid")
    public Address getAddress(){return this.address;}
}
```

And the child entity:

```
@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable{
    private Long fkClientId;
    private Client client;
    //Other fields

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getFkClientId(){return this.fkClientId;}
    public void setFkClientId(Long id){this.fkClientId=id;}

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")        
    public Client getClient(){return this.client;}
}
```

In my test methods I link both objects using their setters, but after persist the entities and execute the line:

```
assertEquals(client.getClientId, client.getAddress().getFkClientId);
```

The test fails with the exception

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<654> but was:<655>
```

I've readed similar questions and problems, but almost all of them are from JPA 1.0, it's supossed that in JPA2.0 the shared keys are automatically assigned. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of such a mapping is shown in [javadoc of `@OneToOne`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html). Note that the side with derived identity should be the owning side of relationship (without `mappedBy`):

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long clientId;     

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "client", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Address address; 

    ...
}

@Entity 
public class Address implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long fkClientId;

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_clientid")
    private Client client; 

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got confused on the owning side of the relationship and how it was implemented in the JPA2.0 spec